# Haskell Syntax: How are functions combined together?

Tags: haskell

a line from [FileIO.hs](https://github.com/tonymorris/fp-course/blob/master/src/Course/FileIO.hs) in [Functional Programming Course exercise](https://github.com/tonymorris/fp-course/tree/master/src/Course)

```
getFile :: FilePath -> IO (FilePath, Chars)
getFile = lift2 (<$>) (,) readFile
```

According to its type signature, `getFile` returns `IO ( FilePath, Chars)`, which means a tuple of filename and its content.

But I just can't figure out why it turns that way.

Why does `FilePath` turn out unchanged in the left, and `readFile` filename filled in the right?

Is `(,)` an Applicative instance too? `(,)` is not an `IO`, so what did `lift2` lift?

And, is there a way to derive those type signatures and get proved?

The syntax I know is that a function follows by its arguments, and it eats one argument on its right hand and becomes a new function. But when it comes to code like that, it looks just like a magic cube to me...

Thank you for helping me out!

Ps. Extra Information as follows

```
instance Functor IO where
  (<$>) =
    P.fmap

lift2 ::
  Applicative f =>
  (a -> b -> c)
  -> f a
  -> f b
  -> f c
lift2 f a b =
  f <$> a <*> b

getFiles :: List FilePath -> IO (List (FilePath, Chars))
getFiles = sequence . (<$>) getFile
```

Comment: That file seems to contain a large amount of pointfree-style code, such as the `getFile` you mention. As it often happens, pointfree leads to almost obfuscated code. In this case, we could instead use the pointful equivalent `getFile f = (,) f <$> readFile f` which is not only clearer but even shorter! Pointfree is sometimes cool, but it should never be used at all costs, just for its own sake.

Comment: Yes!  the lambda way is much clearer. So lift2 just lift unknown argument in this case and make the expression point-free. It all makes sense now. Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at

```
lift2 (<$>) (,) readFile
```

This is indeed straightforward function application:

```
((lift2 (<$>)) (,)) readFile
```

(or `lift2` being applied to three arguments).

The types involved (with uniquely renamed type variables to reduce confusion) are:

```
lift2 :: (Applicative f) => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
(<$>) :: (Functor g) => (j -> k) -> g j -> g k
(,) :: m -> n -> (m, n)
readFile :: FilePath -> IO Chars
```

The first thing in our expression is applying `lift2` to `(<$>)`. That means we need to unify `a -> b -> c` (type of `lift2`'s first argument) and `(Functor g) => (j -> k) -> g j -> g k` (type of `<$>`) somehow.

That is:

```
a -> b -> c = (j -> k) -> g j -> g k
-- where g is a Functor
a = j -> k
b = g j
c = g k
```

This works out. The result type is

```
f a -> f b -> f c
-- where f is an Applicative
```

which is

```
f (j -> k) -> f (g j) -> f (g k)
```

Now this expression (`lift2 (<$>)`) is applied to `(,)`. Again we have to make the types line up:

```
f (j -> k) = m -> n -> (m, n)
```

Here we make use of the property that `->` is right associative (i.e. `a -> b -> c` means `a -> (b -> c)`) and that we can use (curried) prefix notation in types (i.e. `a -> b` is the same as `(->) a b`, which is the same as `((->) a) b`).

```
f (j -> k) = ((->) m) (n -> (m, n))
f = (->) m
j = n
k = (m, n)
```

This also works out. The result type is

```
f (g j) -> f (g k)
```

which (after substituting) becomes

```
((->) m) (g n) -> ((->) m) (g (m, n))
(m -> g n) -> (m -> g (m, n))
```

This expression (`lift2 (<$>) (,)`) is applied to `readFile`. Again, making the types line up:

```
m -> g n = FilePath -> IO Chars
m = FilePath
g = IO
n = Chars
```

And substituting into the result type:

```
m -> g (m, n)
FilePath -> IO (FilePath, Chars)
```

This is the type of the whole `lift2 (<$>) (,) readFile` expression. As expected, it matches the declaration of `getFile :: FilePath -> IO (FilePath, Chars)`.

---

However, we still need to verify that our class constraints (`Functor g`, `Applicative f`) are resolved.

`g` is `IO`, which is indeed a `Functor` (as well as `Applicative` and `Monad`). There are no big surprises here.

`f` is more interesting: `f = (->) m`, so we need to look for an `Applicative` instance for `(->) m`. Such an instance does in fact exist, and its definition contains the answer to what `getFile` actually does.

We can derive what the instance must look like by just looking at the type of `lift2` (as used in `getFile`):

```
lift2 :: (Applicative f) => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
lift2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((->) m) a -> ((->) m) b -> ((->) m) c
lift2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> (m -> a) -> (m -> b) -> (m -> c)
lift2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> (m -> a) -> (m -> b) -> m -> c
```

I.e. `lift2` takes

- a function that combines an `a` and a `b` into a `c`,
- a function that transforms an `m` into an `a`,
- a function that transforms an `m` into a `b`,
- and an `m`,

and produces a `c`.

The only way it can do that is by passing the `m` into the second and third functions and combining their results using the first function:

```
lift2 f g h x = f (g x) (h x)
```

If we inline this definition in `getFile`, we get

```
getFile = lift2 (<$>) (,) readFile
getFile = \x -> (<$>) ((,) x) (readFile x)
getFile = \x -> (,) x <$> readFile x
```

---

**Excercise for the reader:**

`lift2` is actually defined in terms of `<$>` and `<*>`. What are the types of `<$>` and `<*>` in the `Applicative` instance of `(->) m`? What must their definition look like?

Comment: (<*>) f g = \x -> f x (g x)
..................and (<$>) f g = \x -> f (g x) ...........
Is that right? Plus this one, lift2 f g h = \x -> f (g x) (h x), the three functions make some kind of sense I don't get yet...
but first, thx for the detailed explanation and exercise!

Comment: @JohnnyLiao That looks correct. `<*>` is also known as the S combinator; `<$>` is `.` (function composition).